# openstack swit-init can not assign socket port 6002

Tags: sockets, openstack, init, assign, openstack-swift

When I am using openstack to init swift in the storage node with the command:

```
swift-init all start
```

It gives me an error:

[image: error]

So I want to see if port `6002` is busy

```
netstat -plnt
```

[image: ports]

Maybe port `6002` is not in use.
So I am confused.
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show your /etc/swift/account-server.conf ?

Comment: [DEFAULT]
bind_ip = 192.168.209.133
bind_port = 6002
# bind_timeout = 30
# backlog = 4096
user = swift
swift_dir = /etc/swift
devices = /srv/node
mount_check = True
# disable_fallocate = false
#
# Use an integer to override the number of pre-forked processes that will
# accept connections.
# workers = auto
#
# Maximum concurrent requests per worker
# max_clients = 1024
#
# You can specify default log routing here if you want:
# log_name = swift
# log_facility = LOG_LOCAL0
# log_level = INFO

Comment: I think thi IP address is correct

Comment: Just for test purpose, can you change your bind_timeout to 120 seconds?